# Worksheet.copy() fails for _only_ one worksheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, ms-access, charts, vba

I am running VBA code from Access 2010 that opens an Excel 2010 workbook ("Master"), then copies specified sheets from "Master" to a "Client" workbook. This has worked fine until I got to one particular worksheet, where I get:

> Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Worksheet class failed

The line of code is:

```
XLMaster.Sheets(SlideRS.Fields(2).Value).Copy _
         After:=XLClinic.Sheets(XLClinic.Sheets.Count)
```

In this particular instance, this is the 2nd sheet being copied, so the code worked the first time through. This is part of a long debugging process, and this line of code has worked great for more than a dozen other worksheets from the same "Master" workbook.

**Oddly, the copy fails when I try to do it manually, as well.** I've opened "Master", right clicked the particular worksheet that's failing, and tried to copy it, and it just simply fails to do so. I can manually copy other worksheets within the workbook just fine.

The only difference I can identify is that this particular worksheet has 2 pivot charts on it. Other worksheets that copy OK have just data, charts (of varying types), and even pivot charts and regular charts. This is the only one that has *only* pivot charts and not 'regular' charts. Not sure if that's the cause, but that's the only thing I can identify that's possibly different.

For greater context, the line of code comes from this loop:

```
  While Not SlideRS.EOF
    If SlideRS.Fields(1) <> SlideRS.Fields(2) Then                        
     'the worksheet depends on something else, copy it first
     'if the depended upon slide is not in the list of UsedSlides, then add it
      If InStr(1, UsedSlides, SlideRS.Fields(2)) = 0 Then                 
        XLMaster.Sheets(SlideRS.Fields(2).Value).Copy _
                 After:=XLClinic.Sheets(XLClinic.Sheets.Count)
        Set NewSheet = XLClinic.Sheets(XLClinic.Sheets.Count)
        UsedSlides = UsedSlides & "," & NewSheet.Name
        UpdateCharts XLMaster.Sheets(SlideRS.Fields(2).Value), NewSheet
        ProcessDataSheet NewSheet, NewXLName
        Set NewSheet = Nothing
      End If
    End If
    SlideRS.MoveNext
  Wend
```

Again, this code works just fine, it's just this one particular sheet that doesn't want to be copied, either by code or by hand.

Here is what happens when I attempt to copy it by hand in the "Master" spreadsheet.

In a freshly opened copy of my "Master" workbook, I opened the code window and executed `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` in the immediate window (just to be sure), then,

the worksheets before the copy: [image] 
<sup>`VisitsByDemo` is the sheet being copied</sup>

The copy setup: [image]

And after the copy: [image]

There is **no** error message generated by Excel.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210684)?

Comment: Thank you @DonkeyKong, I have seen that. I was already saving the workbook after each and every copy for other reasons. Unfortunately, the copy fails when doing it by hand (not in code), as well, so I think it may be related to the particular worksheet in question.

Comment: Is there a sheet with the same name already in the Client workbook?

Comment: @BranislavKollár No, there is not. When I manually copy a worksheet in the open workbook, it gets named `<sheetname> (2)`. I believe this was happening before I added the code to prevent duplicates in my copy routine, as well.

Comment: **Q1** : When doing manual copy, is there any error, regular excel error? **Q2** : Can this odd behaviour be caused by protection (password)? **Q3** : Does this happen when copying the sheet into new (clean) workbook? **Q4** : Can you make a copy of the sheet inside Master workbook? **Q5**: Can you confirm your thoughts about the pivot charts, by deleting them (in some test workbook of course ;) )?

Comment: **Q1** see update in OP. **Q2** I'd double checked that previously, no, there is no protection on the WB or the WS. **Q3** Hmmm... when doing it manually, I _CAN_ copy it to a brand new workbook. **Q4** No, see updates in OP.  **Q5** Based on Q3, that doesn't seem to be the issue, but I may have to look into it some more

Comment: **Q3** update: I _moved_ the worksheet to a new workbook (unintentionally). That worked. When I tried to _copy_ it to a new workbook, that still fails.

Comment: Thanks, @BranislavKollár. You nudged me enough to look at the pivot charts in more detail, and that's what led me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the the `PivotCharts` were broken.

When I attempted to edit the data source for the PivotCharts, this is what Excel showed me:[image]

When I recreated the PivotCharts on that page, then edit the data source, this is what I see:

[image]

Not sure what happened, but since I created new versions and deleted the originals, `Worksheet.Copy()` works just fine.